# Analysing pre and post intervention MCQ results for significance- which statistical test to use?

Tags: t-test, missing-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, pre-post-comparison

I have ran a teaching course for students. I carried out pre and post session MCQ quizzes to evidence effectiveness of the course, however the marks collected were anonymised (data collected via google forms).

So the participants doing the Pre Session MCQ are the same participants doing the Post Session MCQ- however due to it being anonymised, I cannot pair a pre session MCQ mark with the specific students' post session MCQ mark- therefore as I understand, this means I want to compare sets of data that are unpaired but still dependent?

E.G.
Pre Session Mark | Post Session Mark

1. 70            | 1. 80
2. 40            | 2. 60
3. 90            | 3. 90

The student who achieved the pre session mark of 70 didn't necessarily achieve 80 in the post session MCQ, they may have achieved the 60 or 90 etc. and so on.

The data is not normally distributed, so I will be comparing the median

Therefore, which statistical test can I use, for data which is unpaired but still related/dependent? This has rule out the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Will I have to treat the sets of data as independent and use the Mann-Whitney U Test?

Comment: Is there any extra information that can be used for a (partial) identification?

Comment: Similar Qs:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/how-to-compare-pre-and-post-tests-when-subject-identifier-is-missing, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109731/paired-t-test-when-pairing-is-not-known-and-some-subjects-responded-only-in-on, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541811/how-can-i-set-up-both-paired-and-unpaired-data-for-t-test-in-spss, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/t-test-for-partially-paired-and-partially-unpaired-data, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326691/pre-post-likert-survey-analysis